# C program: memcpy is copying weird data

Tags: c

**C program: The memcpy function seems to be copying the wrong data. The purpose is to take a date parameter of character data (EX: "2019-01-06-20.03.29.004217") and convert it to YYYYMMDD format as an integer.**
My goal is to read only the numbers for year, month, and day when storing them as a string. Then, concatenate all into a single string. Finally, I want to convert the YYYYMMDD string to an integer and return it.

When executed, I only see the year being returned. Is it something that C isn't recognizing? I'm lost as to why this is happening. Please assist.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int getNumDate2 (char *dte);
    

int main()
{
    char prodDate[26 + 1];
    strcpy(prodDate,"2019-01-06-20.03.29.004217");// original date of character data

       printf("%d", getNumDate2(prodDate));

    return 0;
}

int getNumDate2(char *dte)
{
  static char orig_date[26 + 1];
  static char new_date[8 + 1];
  static char year[4 + 1];
  static char mth[2 + 1];
  static char day[2 + 1];
  int new_date_num;

  
  strcpy(orig_date, dte);//store original characters from date
  memcpy(year, orig_date, sizeof(year));//copy year
  memcpy(mth, orig_date+5, sizeof(mth));//copy month  
  memcpy(day, orig_date+8, sizeof(day));//copy year
  
  strcat(new_date, year);//concat date
  strcat(new_date, mth);
  strcat(new_date, day);
  sscanf(new_date,"%d", &new_date_num);//convert string YYYYMMDD to integer YYYYMMDD
  
  return new_date_num;  
}
```

Comment: Just what do you expect `memcpy(year, orig_date, sizeof(year))` to copy, anyway?  How many characters do you think it copies?  What do you think it puts into `year`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I expect that to copy the first 4 characters into year.

Comment: `sizeof(year)` is 5. What makes you expect 4? You might want it to copy first 4 and add a terminating zero char, but that's not what the code does as written.

Comment: So sscanf sees `yyyy-something` and will only parse it until the dash.

Comment: You can use a debugger or `printf()` statements (carefully — you don't have strings to work with because they are not null terminated) to see what's going on.

Comment: @dratenik - YES!! That's what I want!! How to do that? Does memcpy automatically set the terminating NUL when copying char strings?

Comment: memcpy copies raw memory with no special consideration for strings. You may be thinking of strcpy.

Comment: @dratenik - So, how would I set the terminating NUL??

Comment: If you want to terminate year, then you could do a `year[sizeof(year)-1]=0;` after the memcpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use some of what `scanf` can do:

```
int getNumDate2(char *dte) {
    int year, month, day;
    sscanf(dte, "%d-%d-%d", &year, &month, &day);
    return (year*100+month)*100+day;
}
```